# Why do i get invalid client with Live credentials?

Tags: paypal

I have a Paypal business account with an app that i have tested in sandbox mode using the REST API. This works well but when i replace the credentials to live credentials, i get an error with error title: "invalid_client" and error message: "the client credentials are invalid".

I get these credentials from my Paypal account where i created the app. Is there a limitation in using the REST API outside US or does my account have a limitation that I am not aware of?

I have tried approving my app but i don't think that is necessary for the REST API.

Comment: I have the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell in the code that you are in "mode: 'live'" and not "sandbox" anymore.

Answer (score -1):

are outside the US you should have a look at [International Developer Questions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#non-US-dev). Then, take a look at [Manage your applications](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am outside US and I'm aware that some features are limited. I just want to accept payment using paypal but the REST API is not allowing me. I disabled Login with Paypal feature and also disabled Future Payments. For some reason the Future Payments always comes enbale after refresh.